# Can you make thread wait until next thread finishes it's job while using semaphore?

Tags: c++, windows, semaphore

So like the title says I'm trying to create two threads and run them sequentially using `CreateSemaphore()`.

However, when it starts it sometimes runs first thread multiple times then starts second thread.

I tried stopping it by adding a flag but is it possible to use semaphore only?

I'm quite new to C++ threads so sorry if it sounds a little noobie.

Code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>

using namespace std;

HANDLE j_Semaphore;
HANDLE Handler[2];

unsigned int __stdcall addthread(void* data);
unsigned int __stdcall subthread(void* data);

int i = 0;
bool asFlag = true;

int main(){
    j_Semaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL,1,1,NULL);
    if(!j_Semaphore){
        printf("Semaphore Fail\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Original Number: %d\n", i);

        Handler[0] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, addthread, 0, 0, NULL);
        Handler[1] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, subthread, 0, 0, NULL);
        WaitForMultipleObjects(2, Handler, true, INFINITE);

        CloseHandle(Handler[0]);
        CloseHandle(Handler[1]);

        CloseHandle(j_Semaphore);
    }
    system("pause");
}

unsigned int __stdcall addthread(void* data)
{
    DWORD runSemaphore;
    BOOL releaseSema;

    while(true){
        if(asFlag == true){
            runSemaphore = WaitForSingleObject((HANDLE) j_Semaphore, INFINITE);
            if(runSemaphore == WAIT_FAILED) {
                printf("add semaphore run error\n");
            }   //else WAIT_FAILED check end
            else if(runSemaphore == WAIT_ABANDONED){
                printf("add semaphore WAIT_ABANDONED error\n");
            }   //else WAIT_ABANDONED check end
            else if(runSemaphore == WAIT_TIMEOUT){
                printf("add semaphore WAIT_TIMEOUT error\n");
                do{     //release semaphore until successful
                    releaseSema = ReleaseSemaphore(j_Semaphore, 1, NULL);
                    if(releaseSema == 0) {
                        printf("semaphore sub release error\n");
                    }   //releaseSema check end
                }while(releaseSema == 0);
            }   //else WAIT_TIMEOUT check end
            else if(runSemaphore == WAIT_OBJECT_0){
                i = i + 5;
                printf("add: %d\n", i);

                releaseSema = ReleaseSemaphore(j_Semaphore, 1, NULL);
                if(releaseSema == 0) {
                    printf("semaphore add release error\n");
                }   //releaseSema check end
                asFlag = false;
            }   //else WAIT_OBJECT_0 check end
        }   //if flag check end
    }   //while loop end
    return 0;
}

unsigned int __stdcall subthread(void* data)
{
    DWORD runSemaphore;
    BOOL releaseSema;

    while(true){
        if(asFlag == false){
            runSemaphore = WaitForSingleObject((HANDLE) j_Semaphore, INFINITE);
            if(runSemaphore == WAIT_FAILED){
                printf("sub semaphore run error\n");
            }   //else WAIT_FAILED check end
            else if(runSemaphore == WAIT_ABANDONED){
                printf("sub semaphore WAIT_ABANDONED error\n");
            }   //else WAIT_ABANDONED check end
            else if(runSemaphore == WAIT_TIMEOUT){
                printf("sub semaphore WAIT_TIMEOUT error\n");
                do{     //release semaphore until successful
                    releaseSema = ReleaseSemaphore(j_Semaphore, 1, NULL);
                    if(releaseSema == 0) {
                        printf("semaphore sub release error\n");
                    }   //releaseSema check end
                }while(releaseSema == 0);
            }   //else WAIT_TIMEOUT check end
            else if(runSemaphore == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
                i = i - 5;
                printf("sub: %d\n", i);

                releaseSema = ReleaseSemaphore(j_Semaphore, 1, NULL);
                if(releaseSema == 0) {
                    printf("semaphore sub release error\n");
                }   //releaseSema check end
                asFlag = true;
            }   //else WAIT_OBJECT_0 check end
        }   //if flag check end
    }   //while loop end
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why all of this microsoft black magic? Can you use [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) and [std::condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) ?

Comment: My c++ version doesn't support those two. I have to build something from an older version so it is easier to integrate to newer versions so I can't really use them. I did try them out on different version and it worked beautifully though so thanks for that.